# ComponentDidMount call twice due to navigation reset

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native. I add a splash screen in my app which is the initial route for my app and I use setTimeout which call a function after 3 seconds in which I navigate to my Login Page. For this, I am using react-navigation. When user opens my app he lands to the splash screen and after 3 seconds, he navigates to the login page. It works fine but when android user press the back button it comes back to the splash screen. For this reason, I reset my navigation in componentDidMount function of splash screen as

```
   const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login'}),
              ],
            });
            that.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But my login page renders two times. But if I only navigate to the login page with this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
```

it works fine. Please help me out how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens due to my login component. In my login component, I am setting the router param value in my componentWillMount which is used by my login header.

```
 this.props.navigation.setParams({ isLoading: false });
```

Due to this my splash component calls again and comes back to login page. Therefore Login component renders two times.

Comment: @Pullkit, So from where, you have set params for navigation options?